# Android - creating push notifications after something happens on the server

Tags: android

I have been reading about creating push notifications using TCP/IP and it seems like the steps described there may be somewhat outdated" http://tokudu.com/2010/how-to-implement-push-notifications-for-android/

Really I only need to alert the user that "xyz action has happened on abc app"

I was earlier advised to use UrbanAirship, but I am not certain how that fits into things. I guess it is because I need to send the alerts from a secure connection.

But how do I send the alert? Do I just need the phone-id or something like that? What would be a good tutorial for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code for server part:

```
package yourpackage.android.gcm.server;

import com.google.android.gcm.server.Message;
import com.google.android.gcm.server.MulticastResult;
import com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender;

import java.util.ArrayList;

class Notify {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
                                       // this API key    
            Sender sender = new Sender("AIzaSyCn3N2OIm-EDtiGwTyQfSIB8NRvDtIOx30");

            ArrayList<String> devicesList = new ArrayList<String>();
//add you deviceID
            devicesList.add("APA91bELVJbxB_NLnLbTkkkX87SDdkJc6OfCN2slhC9t4cLq-KA32eGgiW4-Gi--ZEsEMKIh0AtYJMs5rQGswfm3cH1qK853WcpV98bkaplAaC5AiycDmifuVFSRl21vgf-Rqj0dCrFF");
                        //devicesList.add("APA91bHIdM4XGqrjJLTuwCX5OOrTYG4ACXYEVkZDM1bPs5qFdzJP4Bpql-sZqyKB8BU7fDtdxB84aTygHLyASYg_XNY6lqrcA4wj4sZHJXGVFzz_0UEADMfFCx9NAfRZxunIYso_dkBa");
            //APA91bFA-i2l3iEMnIBs0JK80pTLHOsE7p1s-DysRpKGas1MQOVILyIs9xwY7soysSWGz5Uif68uXR6F5Xn0tCTYesv78uQZxhC310a1cvf8aFohhfMGY6awbOSg3t1GRz2i3U-8kVSF
            // Use this line to send message without payload data
            // Message message = new Message.Builder().build();

            // use this line to send message with payload data
            Message message = new Message.Builder()
                    //.collapseKey("message")
                    //.timeToLive(241000)
                    .delayWhileIdle(true)
                    .addData("message", "Your message send")
                    .build();


                   /**/
            // Use this code to send to a single device
            // Result result = sender
            // .send(message,
            // "APA91bGiRaramjyohc2lKjAgFGpzBwtEmI8tJC30O89C2b3IjP1CuMeU1h9LMjKhmWuZwcXZjy1eqC4cE0tWBNt61Kx_SuMF6awzIt8WNq_4AfwflaVPHQ0wYHG_UX3snjp_U-5kJkmysdRlN6T8xChB1n3DtIq98w",
            // 1);

            // Use this for multicast messages
            MulticastResult result = sender.send(message, devicesList, 1);
            //sender.send(message, devicesList, 0);

            System.out.println(result.toString());
            if (result.getResults() != null) {
                int canonicalRegId = result.getCanonicalIds();
                if (canonicalRegId != 0) {
                }
            } else {
                int error = result.getFailure();
                System.out.println(error);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

and you can use this code for client  part:

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super("");
        Log.d("GCMIntentService", senderId);
    }


     private void genNotification(Context context, String message) {

         notify(context, message);
         PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

         boolean isScreenOn = pm.isScreenOn();

         Log.e("screen on.................................", ""+isScreenOn);

         if(isScreenOn==false) {

             PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE,"MyLock");

             wl.acquire(10000);
             PowerManager.WakeLock wl_cpu = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,"MyCpuLock");

             wl_cpu.acquire(10000);
         }
     }

    public static void notify(Context context, String message)  {
        int icon = R.drawable.icon;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
        context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationListView.class);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        NotificationDataHelper helper = new NotificationDataHelper(context);
        Notification notification;
        notification = new Notification(icon, "message", when);
            notificationIntent.putExtra("message", message);
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, "message", intent);
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, msg, intent);
        }
        //set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        notificationIntent.setAction("notification");
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onError(Context arg0, String arg1) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("GCM", "RECEIVED A MESSAGE");
        Log.d("GCM", "RECEIVED A MESSAGE");
        Log.d("GCM", "RECEIVED A MESSAGE");
        Log.d("GCM", "RECEIVED A MESSAGE");

            genNotification(context, intent.getStringExtra("message"));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {

    }

}
```

and at first you registered device http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html like this tutorial and get deviceID and you can send message for the device

```
private void registerGCM() {
        GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
        //GCMRegistrar.unregister(this);
        //Log.d("info", "unregistered....." + GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this));
        GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
        if (GCMRegistrar.isRegistered(this)) {
            Log.d("info", GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this));
        }
        final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);

        if (regId.equals("")) {
            GCMRegistrar.register(this, "1013733918417");
            Log.d("info", GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this));
        } else {
            Log.d("info", "already registered as " + regId);
        }


            GCMIntentService.notify(this, null);

    }
```

Comment: what I have happening is my program makes an asynch remote call. My server is made with PHP but I am not sure what are the ids that are used in your example for the server part.  And on the client part, if I just paste that code, is it relatively standard code for a user to recieve a notification on their device?

Comment: And by the way, so far I am not collecting any device-id from the users. How can I do that? Is that a relatively simple thing to do?

Comment: i think, you can save device id to database for userid